# Multiple workstation for one chef-server/org

Tags: git, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a chef server running with a few nodes registered on it . At the moment i have just ONE workstation managing and controlling the nodes with cookbooks written in my chef-repo dir.

I have two other engineers i want them to be able to manage the same chef server from their own workstations ,i already added them to the same org. Next is to setup their workstations

**Question:**

1. Whats the standard way for them to setup their own workstation to also manage same chef-server and nodes ?
2. When they do the git clone part of the setup , they have completetly newly synced chef-repo from the git `git clone https://github.com/chef/chef-repo.git`  . Is there a way to share the same repo across three different workstations ?
3. In this scenario how will you manage recipes and cookbooks?

Hope my question is quite understandable , i will be available for any clarifications

Answer (score 0):

1. It really depends on your operating systems. You'll need the chefdk, but the gems you use and locations of directories and files will depend on if you're Mac, Linux or Windows.
2. Unfortunately I know very little about this. My shop uses svn and we all work off the same repo.
3. Berkshelf is used to manage versions and dependencies, which is what it sounds like you're asking about. You'll need the berks gem which might even be default in the latest chefdk and you'll manage your dependencies in your metadata.rb file. your berksfile.rb will be where you set the paths to where the depended on cookbooks are stored along with the source of any supermarkets you're using and the berksfile.loc file will have a graph of dependencies, automatically created by berkshelf.